# WAMP error #2002 - restoring "data" folder not working

Tags: mysql, wamp, access-denied

Ok, i know that there is a million of similar questions on Stackoveflow and all over the internet, but non of them was useful to me, so i had to ask it again.
Here is my problem, i wanted to move my WAMP, so i installed WAMP on different location, moved "data" folder from old mysql folder to a new location, but after restarting wamp, i got yellow icon, mysql was not running and ofc i wasn't able to access /phpmyadmin gettin' error

```
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

When i switch back default "data" folder everything gets back to normal ( that mean that FW is not a problem), dont know what is the problem since i always used the same technique to back up wamp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well did you look at the `mysql error log` to see why MySQL did not start?

Comment: i dont have mysql error log file in "logs" folder.

Comment: Then look at the Windows Event Viewer for error messages from MYSQL

Comment: Its says
    InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_relay_log_info uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace wptestserver/wp_terms which uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\wptestserver\wp_terms.ibd

Comment: Ive deleted corrupted folder, and after that wamp was able to start, showed green icon, but i still wasnt able to access phpmyadmin, now gettin' a new error


#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Check `\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php` is there a password set in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'SOME_PASSWORD';` if so remove it untill you set a new password on the `root` userid

Comment: That sort a problem, now everything works fine, thanks, its very strange, because i did the same thing, earlier before, but then phpmyadmin asked me to log in and i wasn't able to log, no matter what i typed in.

phpmyadmin didnt let me login, no matter what i do, now everything